# insert associative data to array of associative data in php

Tags: php, arrays, merge

I'm trying to find out which is the correct way to add associative data to an array of associative data.

I have something like this:

```
$values = array('data1' => $data1, 'data2' => $data2, => 'data3' => $data3 );
```

now what if I want to add for example $data4 as 'data4' to $values?

Should I use `array_merge()` ?

like `$values = array_merge($values, array('data4', $data4));`

or is there a better / more correct way?

Comment: $values = array_merge($values, array('data4'=> $data4));

Comment: I'd rather use [array_push()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php)

Comment: I tried to use `array_push($values, array('data4' => $data4));` and I get an error like argument 1 must be array, integer given ... integer??

Comment: There's rarely a good reason to use `array_push()`.

Comment: Ignoring the invalid array in your post, array_push only works with values, not key=>value. The result would be $values[4] = array('data4' => $data4);

Answer (score 2):

You could keep it simple :

```
$value['data4'] = $data4;
```

Comment: That's actually a great answer in my opinion. Simple and it's got the job done.